# How to show more than one property using angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

```
    <select id="mySelect" [(ngModel)]="selectedItem" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)" name="options"  class="select-project"  >            
      <optgroup label="Recent Tasks"  >
        <option *ngFor="let item of 1stList"  [ngValue]="item" ">{{item.title}}</option>
        </optgroup>
      <optgroup label="All Tasks" >
        <option *ngFor="let item of 2ndList" [ngValue]="item" >{{item.title}}</option>
      </optgroup>
```

Above it's my code for the select  html element.
My item has title,id,year,price, the desired result is to show the data from the Object like that: **Id-title-price** with dash between each property, problem is that I am achieving only to show only one property, not 3 of them at once.
When user selects the desired option I need to take the whole information of the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something you just need to add the required properties to the markup.

```
<option *ngFor="let item of 1stList"  [ngValue]="item">
    {{item.Id}}-{{item.title}}-{{item.price}}
</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
<option *ngFor="let item of 1stList"  [ngValue]="item">
 {{item.id}}-{{item.title}}-{{item.price}}
</option>
```